# Arduino PS2X module not working with controller

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been trying to use the PS2X module to try to use my PS1 remote with my arduino (I am guessing that PS1 controllers will work because they are virtually the same ). The problem is that I don't want to download the module from the original website because it is not secure (it had HTTP instead of HTTPS) and the download file could contain viruses. Instead I got it off the arduino website. I have wired my controller correctly and have triple checked that all the wires are in the right positions and they seem to be. I then used the arduino example program given by the safely downloaded file. I complied it onto my arduino and I got the following message in the serial "`No controller found, check wiring, see readme.txt to enable debug. visit www.billporter.info for troubleshooting tips
Unknown Controller type`." I then looked into the text file to debug it and it told me to uncomment 2 of the lines which is what I did. I then ran the example program file again like how the readme file told me to, and I still get the same errors.

link github:https://github.com/madsci1016/Arduino-PS2X

link to the main: http://www.billporter.info/2011/03/27/arduino-playstation-2-controller-library-troubleshooting-guide/

wiring:
[image: wiring]

how I have wired it:
[image: me wiring]

Comment: @jsotola it LITERALLY means "the same"

Comment: Which example in which library? Please provide a link, if possible for the github site of the library. Also show your wiring

Comment: @chrisl shown above

Comment: You still didn't include the link. Do you mean [this library](https://github.com/madsci1016/Arduino-PS2X)?

Comment: yes I do mean that one sorry